# Instantiating a class and running its methods in a different JVM

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

Let's say I have a class `X` with a no-arg constructor and a method `m` that I need to run in a fresh new JVM for wizardry purposes.

My first thought lay in calling it from the command line (`org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine`) but now I'm stuck with the fact that `X` doesn't have a `main()` method (I'm assuming the only way to call Java code through the command line is passing to `java` a class that contains a static `main` method, right?). I can through a quick detour create my own `main()` method in the calling class, and have as its contents

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String classToInstantiate = args[some index];
  ...
}
```

but I was wondering if there's some cleaner way to accomplish this.

**To recap, I need to know the cleanest way to instantiate an arbitrary class as well as invoke arbitrary methods on that class, on a different JVM than that of my main code.**

Thanks

Comment: What are you *really* trying to accomplish? (rather than telling us the solution that you want to use)

Comment: I need to run totally isolated code, absolutely untouched by my main process.

Comment: And creating a classloader doesn't do what you want? If not, why not?

Comment: Because different classloaders will use the same heap memory, and I don't want to mix heap memories (I want to record the heap memory usage of that class I want to run -- that's it.)

Comment: In that case, the solution that you already described is your only choice. If you're going to start a new JVM, it needs a `main()` to call. If you need to invoke arbitrary methods on the instantiated class, you'll need to devise some protocol for the JVMs to communicate.

Comment: Maybe goovry can help you. http://groovy.codehaus.org/

Comment: Basically, you want to use JNI, to set up the new process/JVM and start execution of the class.  But for that you generally need to drop into C code.

Comment: @parsifal - JNI can start a JVM somewhere other than at `main`.

Comment: (But, of course, there's no big deal in having a dummy class with `main`, to be the entry point of the new JVM.  The only reason for using a different mechanism is if the parms you want to pass cannot easily be reduced to character strings.)

Comment: Using JNI would be an overkill, and would introduce incompatibilities between OSes, because of the C code, I guess.

Comment: @HotLicks - technically true, but in that case you're simply substituting a C (or C++, or whatever) `main()` for the Java `main()`. Every process needs a well-defined entry point.

Comment: @devouredelysium - The C code would be pretty "stock" -- not much that could possibly be system-dependent.

Comment: @parsifal - What you would be substituting would be custom C code that replaces the stock C code implementing the `java` command.  JNI is used to invoke `main()` in the normal case, after all.

Comment: @HotLicks - I have no idea what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @parsifal - My point is that you're not substituting for `main`.  You'd be substituting for `java`.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 9, [a REPL](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/kulla/) is included within the OpenJDK. This way, you could invoke the code programatically from the console by using this REPL. It might even be ported back to Java 8 in an upcoming update. Today, in Java 8, this is possible with a few distractions by running the Nashorn REPL.

Alternatively, you can write a program that does this job for you or use a REPL that is packaged with other languages for the JVM such as Scala.